# Can we force the list view Filters Pane to have the ability to filter all the files, even the ones inside folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, managed-navigation

I am working on a sharepoint online team site collection, and i have a document library which contain 3 managed metadata columns named (Department, Main Category & Sub Category).

Previously, inside sharepoint 2013 and inside the classic UI on sharepoint online, i was able to filter the documents using the managed metadata navigation and filtering feature, by configuring managed metadata columns as follow:-

[image]

which will allow us to filter the documents as follow:-

[image]

But the above will not work on modern UI. and alternatively we have the modern way of filtering documents/items using the "Filters Pane", as follow:-
[image]

but the main problem when using the Filters pane, is that it will not filter the documents found inside the folders, of course unless we navigate tot the folder.

So can anyone advice on how we can filter all the documents when using modern UI? i know that i can create a new list view and chose to show all documents without folders, but doing so will raise a threshold error, since our document library already have 10,000 ++ documents.

Comment: I am guessing that search is not an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @SlavenSemper if i can do this type of filtering using search then there is not any restriction from my side.. but not sure how search can help me in achieving my need?

Comment: if you create managed metadata then you can limit your search by `Department:SomeDepartment` or any of the combination of managed metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

1. Change the library settings to show all the documents without folders
2. Identify column filters that can lower the number of items that would be displayed and Pin those columns to filter pane
3. Navigate to site pages , create a 'link' with those filters in url, something like
   [image]

http://siteurl/Forms/AllItems.aspx?useFiltersInViewXml=1**&FilterField1=Dept&FilterValue1=2**&FilterType1=Counter&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterOp1=In&siteid=*Sid*&webid=*WebID*&uniqueid=*ID*
 4. This is how it appears by default , when you click on the link
[image]
 5. It loads with the default filters and you can click/change the fiters as per the requirement

Comment: showing all documents without folders will raise the threshold error in our case, as we have 30,000 ++ documents..

Comment: You have to choose appropriate filters , for eg: You can have filter by department IT which may have lesser number of records